# Как добавить кириллицу в PostgresSQL?

Tags: postgresql, кодировка

Нужно хранить строки на русском языке в базе PostgresSQL.

И хотя при выводе всех баз у каждой стоит `UTF8` на русском языке общения не выходит(...

```
postgres=# \l

                               List of databases
     Name      |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges   
---------------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 auto_services | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 lesson        | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 parser        | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 postgres      | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 task_manager  | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 template0     | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
               |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1     | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
               |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 tracker       | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 user_storage  | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     |
```

Ну и при попытке добавить что-то на русском языке, консоль даже не печатает символы а только знаки вопросов:

```
postgres=# insert into test_table (name) values ('??????');// вопросы это попытка ввести русские буквы.
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xd1 0xd0
```

При этом:

```
postgres=# SHOW client_encoding;
 client_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
```

Все это работает под Mac.

Помогите пожалуйста поправить эту проблему.

Comment: Так может проблемы с консолью, а не с PostgreSQL? Попробуйте с клиента добавить что-нибудь. Ну или через менеджер БД какой-нибудь.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin, прав, скорее всего с консолью беда, там используется кодировка CP-866.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin я тоже сначала так подумал, но не в консоле PostgresSQL все нормально работает. Или у postgres своя консоль?

Comment: Вы описали, где работает, а где **не** работает, забыли. А это даже важнее.

Comment: @D-side в смысле где не работает, не работает в SQL Shell(psql) под Mac OS.

Comment: @Pavel это я неверно интерпретировал ваше "Все это работает под Mac." Надо смотреть, в какой кодировке запущен клиент. Видно, что он **думает**, что в UTF-8, а текст в какой кодировке он реально получает? У нас есть `0xd1` и `0xd0`, скорее всего это две первых кириллических буквы, введённых вами. И это явно **не** UTF-8. Что там на самом деле, известно?

Comment: @D-side а то есть ввод может быть на какой-то левой кодировке а как узнать в какой кодировке происходит ввод?

Comment: @Pavel можно сопоставить по байтам, зная, что вы ввели.

Comment: @D-side звучит как приговор(

Comment: @Pavel почему? Байты psql вывел. Остаётся только узнать, что вы вводили.

Comment: @D-side на букву "ц" показывает "?" и :invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xd1 0x3b

Comment: @Pavel полный введённый текст и новый текст ошибки в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: @D-side вот это полный я специально нашел букву на которой проблема(есть кириллические символы которые работают) todo_list=# ?;
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xd1 0x3b

Comment: Ага. `0x3b` это `;`. В ASCII и ещё много где. А вот где `0xD1` это `ц`, сходу не скажу, надо пробить по кодировкам.

Comment: @D-side да но разве важно в какой кодировке он получает. Важно как поменять эту кодировку? Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: Можно и с этого угла подойти. Потому что подходящих кодировок я не нашёл. И поскольку за это направление ввода отвечает ваш эмулятор терминала на Маке, и это должно быть где-то в его настройках, а у меня нет Мака, дальше я ничем помочь не могу.